# How is it possible that Robocop kept his human brain without rotting or damage?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

In the 1987 Robocop movie, we can see they used Officer Alex Murphy's dead body to make Robocop.

The makers of Robocop used Alex Murphy's human brain & fixed it to his new body & covered it with his helmet.

When I google about how long a human brain can keep without rotting after death below details came:

> "The brain can survive for up to about six minutes after the heart stops. The reason to learn cardiopulmonary resuscitation (CPR) is that if CPR is started within six minutes of cardiac arrest, the brain may survive the lack of oxygen. After about six minutes without CPR, however, the brain begins to die."

How is possible that Robocop kept his human brain without rotting or damage? Is it because technical achievement or just movie makers faked It?

Comment: They kept Cain's brain alive in a jar with bubbling fluid. Just sorta floating there

Comment: @Valorum are you referencing some kind of sequel?

Comment: @HorusKol - Robocop 2; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_m90Rm0RX-8

Comment: @Valorum yes, I know... Sorry, I just remember you sometimes not acknowledging certain sequels/prequels in certain movie/TV/book franchises... Apologies if I'm confusing you with someone else

Comment: @HorusKol - I've seen plenty of people claiming that Robocop 2 and the various sequels and reboots don't really count. I prefer to take a more holistic approach.

Comment: You can see Robocop's brain in this scene https://youtu.be/GBFe3ohr1PE?t=1905

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Thank you for he Video Clip.. i was looking for it. in the Video we can see clearly Alex Murphy's (Robocop) Original Brain. if they transferd his memory to some other gadget why did they put His Original brain to the metel body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Murphy was still alive when the paramedics arrived, though barely clinging on. While he had been shot in the head ( amongst his many wounds), his brain was likely still receiving oxygenated blood, especially under the care of the paramedics.

Murphy only dies after falling into the "care" of OCP, who build an entirely new body for Murphy/Robocop, which includes a new support system for the extremely limited organic remains incorporated into his body.

From [an interview with the director](http://collider.com/paul-verhoeven-elle-robocop-reboot-interview/), would appear that almost no organic brain tissue remains in Robocop with his memories being transferred some electronic storage instead.

> His brain is gone and he has only flashes of memory and needs to go to a computer to find out who he even is.

So, really, by this point, there is no brain to decay away.

Comment: If his brain is gone then why would there be a life support system needed?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix there's his face and tongue, and some other organic tissue, which would need nutrients